# Gauss Seidel - NOT converging to actual solution

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

For the following problem:
using Gauss-Seidel iteration method using partial pivoting find the solution of following system up to 5 iterations with initial values $(x,y,z,w) = (0,0,0,0)$

$10x-7y+3z+5w = 6$

$-6x+8y-z-4w = 5$

$3x+y+4z+11w = 2$

$5x-9y-2z+4w = 7$

My approach:

Partial pivoting:-
reorganising equaitons so that $|a_{ij}/a_{ii}| < 1 \forall i,j$

$x = (6+7y-3z-5w)/10$

$y = (-7+5x-2z+4w)/9$

$z = (2-3x-y-11w)/4$

$w = (-5-6x+8y-z)/4$

---

**Putting initial values $(0,0,0,0)$**

1st iteration: $(0.6, -0.4444, 0.1611, -3.0792)$

2nd iteration: $(1.7801, -1.1931, 7.9309, -8.2892)$

3rd iteration: $(1.5301, -5.3742, 23.4912, -20.1664)$

4rth iteration: $(-0.1261, -15.0310, 59.8100, -46.0753)$

5th iteration: $(-4.8270, -37.2285, 140.1344, -103.5000)$

Why are these values not converging to actual answer **$(5,4,-7,1)$** even after 5 iterations. They seem to diverge on every further iteration. Could you tell me, did I do pivoting correctly? Please clarify!

Comment: Are you sure that the task is to solve this system specifically with Gauß-Seidel? Look up again what "diagonally dominant" means, this matrix is far apart from that property, even with pivoting. If the iteration matrix is in consequence not contractive in all directions, the expanding eigen-directions will dominate the iteration, leading to divergence.

Comment: Or did the task demand to use the non-iterative Gauß algorithm with partial pivoting, that is, computing a PLU decomposition and then solving the triangular systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are no where wrong. The problem is not intrinsically convergent. Defining $$v=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}$$and $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0.7&-0.3&-0.5\\{5\over 9}&0&-{2\over 9}&{4\over 9}\\-{3\over 4}&-{1\over 4}&0&{11\over 4}\\-{3\over 2}&2 &-{1\over 4}&0\end{bmatrix}\\b=\begin{bmatrix}0.6\\-{7\over 9}\\0.5\\-{5\over 4}\end{bmatrix}$$you are trying to iteratively find $v$ such that $$v_0=\underline{0}\\,\\v_{n+1}=Av_n+b$$such that $v_{n}\to v^*$ where $v^*$ is the answer of the set of the equations. Note that $$v_n=A^n v_0+(A^{n-1}+\cdots +I)b=(A^{n-1}+\cdots +I)b$$which is convergent only if all the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $A$ are less that $1$. Since this is not the case here (the eigs are $\approx\{-1.84,0.25,0.62,1.47\}$) then we have divergence.